# UWP Microsoft AdControl Resume and Suspend Does not work

Tags: uwp, ads, resume, suspend, windows-dev-center

So the adcontrol does not work when navigation with both pages in the memory. So if I go from page1 to page 2 while I have an AdControl on page1. When I return to page1 from page2 the adcontrol disappears and I can not refresh the adcontrol. The error says that its not visible. I made sure that it is visible and made sure the parent is visible and it all checks out. If I remove the adcontrol and re add it then it works. But it does not stay in the memory of the page. The page its self is kept in memory as I can see that on dynamic controls being saved on navigation. So the issue is with adcontrol. Can someone please let me know how I can set the adcontrol once on page1 and keep it there forever. When I return to page1 I would like to refresh the adcontrol ad. I dont want to keep recreatig the adcontrol each time I load page1 as this causes a memory leak. MS has not explanation for this error. Please help. Thanks.

- Im using updated AdControl SDK.
- Im using the new Creators Update SDK (Error is for all SDKs)
- Using VS 2017.
- So the issue is no my SDKS, or my machine, or my tools.

Comment: This could be a issue also existing for other developers. The workaround currently is to disable the page's Navigation Cache: `NavigationCacheMode="Disabled`. I will report this issue to related team to have an investigation.

Comment: Thanks. This issue has been in W10 AdControl since day one all the way back to the original launch of W10. Also this same issue is on WP8.1 and Windows Phone 10 UWP and on XBOX UWP. If I disable the cache the adcontrol still eats the memory. So disabling navigation cache does nothing to improve the problem. Are there any other suggestions?